# Manage i18n content in the area between .po-files and flatpages

Tags: python, django, django-i18n

I have a django project utilizing flatpages for pages with primarily static content and .po-files for shorter strings, headers, buttons etc. But I'm having trouble exploring alternatives for the block of content that a customer would want to edit themselves through the admin or a customized form that I can include in templates?

I have thought about taking a CMS approach based on existing framework but because the project works great without cms-functionality for maybe 90 % of the content I do not wanna go this way, for now.

My first idea is to create a own model 'text_blocks' and use something like [django-modeltranslation](https://github.com/deschler/django-modeltranslation) and populate the views context with the correct objects.

My question is first if the approach above seems reasonable but primarily what alternatives for managing this type of content am I missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running my custom solution with my own app and [django-modeltranslation](http://code.google.com/p/django-modeltranslation/) for a while I stumbled on [django-page-cms](http://github.com/batiste/django-page-cms) which seems to make it even simplier for customer admin users to edit pages.